# Can't install sap/hana-client driver NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, hana

Im trying to install the sap/hana-client driver so i can connect my application with sap hana database but im getting this error instead i followed this commands:

```
npm init --yes 
npm i express 
npm i @sap/hana-client
```

[image: sap/hana-client driver installation error]

Log file :

[2022-09-30T08_42_13_653Z-debug-0](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d4D11CQrAxS3C_9rdKMEtqMzN8r57fha/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: your errors in the log: `verbose stack HttpErrorGeneral: 404 Not Found - GET` and `Not Found - GET` say that it is simple network connection error. Check your connectivity and routes and re-try